# Suspects found dead?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Murder suspects found **dead**.

Is ***dead*** in this sentence an adjective or an adverb? Why ? Can you explain with examples ?

Comment: Adjectivie......

Comment: You don't give any context, but the natural interpretation is that someone has found the dead bodies of some people who were suspects in a murder case. It looks like a news headline.

Comment: The murder suspects are dead.  Therefore "dead" is an adjective.  To be an adverb, "dead" would have to be attached to "found", which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

"find" is verb that can take an object and a complement. The complement may be an adjective that describes the object.

> I found Joe happy and contented.

In a passive form the object becomes the subject

> Joe was found happy and contented.

And in headlines, the linking verb "was" is sometimes omitted

> Joe found happy and contented

> Murder suspects found dead

Dead is an adjective that describes the murder suspects.

Comment: I wouldn't like to be an adjective that described a murder suspect, then. Sounds dangerous.

Comment: Not dangerous if the suspects are dead.

Comment: *Blessed is he who trusts in the Lord* and *Dead is an adjective that described murder suspects* :-)

Answer (score 0):

The detective fell over the edge of a cliff and fell right onto the murder suspects. He found them dead, because he fell over 100 feet (adverb). He found them dead because they were hit by the detective falling from great height (adjective).

It is an adjective referring to the suspects. I tried hard to create a sentence where the person finding them was dead (adverb).

And usually adverbs are formed by adding -ly. However, deadly has a different meaning.